# AWS PHP SDK with Composer - missing sdk.class.php

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php

Environment: MAC - Mountain Lion
I am trying to use the AWS PHP SDK for a project. I followed the Amazon web site's SDK installation directions (through composer) -- using the following [Link to AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/sdk-php2-installing-the-sdk.html#sdk-php2-installing-via-composer)

I created the file compser.json. Contens:

```
{
  "require": {
      "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
  }
}
```

From the command line, I typed:

```
curl -s "http://getcomposer.org/installer" | php
```

Then

```
php composer.phar install
```

A new directory appeared "vendor" and inside it, the AWS SDK 2 was automatically installed.

The problem is that I am expecting (per the code example I'm trying to follow), I am expecting to see the following file:

```
vendor/aws/aws-sdk-for-php/sdk.class.php
```

But it's not there. Could this be referencing an older version of the SDK?

The automatically generated by the "php composer.phar install" command: vendor/autoload.php looks like this:

```
<?php
// autoload.php generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit25a7292f83dd9a43a459f6c2e51befba::getLoader();
```

Is it possible that the file: sdk.class.php is valid for version 1 of the SDK, but not version 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entirely correct. `sdk.class.php` is a file that exists in SDK 1.x, but not 2.x.

The correct instructions are in the [SDK2 README](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/README.md#installing-the-sdk).

Comment: It looks like it's possible to have both 1 & 2 and an easy way to do it is via composer.